# Traverse to the second table using dom parser

Tags: jquery

I have code like

```
<table>
</table>
<table>
</table>
<table>
</table>
```

i want to traverse to the second table using jquery. How do i do it.

Comment: Last time I checked `<table>` is the markup for tables, not `<html>` :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the second `table` element by this expression:

```
var secondTable = $('table').eq(1); // index is zero-based
```